# Convert simple Flash AS2 code to AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I'm a Flash beginner and followed a tutorial: http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/018/tutorial.php
... to learn how to make a "live paint/draw" effect. I didn't realize that if I made something in AS2, I wouldn't be able to embed it (and have it work) into my root AS3 file, where I've got a bunch of other stuff going on. I've tried following tips on how to change AS2 code to AS3, but it just doesn't work. I know it's simple code, and that some genius out there can figure it out, but I'm at a loss. Please help!

Here's the AS2 code:

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("myLine", 0);

_root.onMouseDown = function() {
   myLine.moveTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
   ranWidth = Math.round((Math.random() * 10)+2);
   myLine.lineStyle(ranWidth, 0xff0000, 100);
   _root.onMouseMove = function() {
      myLine.lineTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
   }
}

_root.onMouseUp = function() {
   _root.onMouseMove = noLine;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question, but a request to have someone do your work for you. If you were struggling with the AS3 conversion, next time please post your attempt at conversion so that we can guide you in the right direction, rather then having someone do your work for you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the exact same thing in AS3

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var ranWidth:Number;

//creation of a new clip (Sprite is the base class of MovieClip, 
//it's the same without the unneeded timeline)
var myLine:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(myLine);

//in AS3 the main container is stage, not _root
//you see here the main difference between beginner AS3 and beginner AS2: 
//event listeners
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown); 


function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ranWidth = Math.round((Math.random() * 10)+2);
    myLine.graphics.lineStyle(ranWidth, 0xff0000, 100);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
}

//nesting function in other functions is not a good practice
function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm eternally grateful!

Comment: I accept your eternal gratefulness and I'd be glad you accept my answer :) Signed, Kodiak, Flash Afficionado

Comment: I really do appreciate your efforts Kodiak, but remember: this site is about helping people with questions, not doing peoples work for them.

Comment: @Nicolle; Also, despite not actually being a 'question', you should mark this as the correct answer since Kodiak was so helpful.

Comment: Yes, I know, bad three-years-ago me!